# Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss

while I am running my java project I got below error

```
IFMIS-ear .......................................... FAILURE [ 26.330 s]
IFMIS .............................................. SKIPPED
BUILD FAILURE
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Total time: 01:07 min
 Finished at: 2019-04-23T10:57:35+05:30
 Final Memory: 49M/660M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR]   Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:JBoss-as-maven- 
plugin:7.4.Final: deploy (default) on project IFMIS-ear: Deployment failed 
and was rolled back. -> [Help 1] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please 
 read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the 
command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :IFMIS-ear
```

I am new to this java development,kindly anyone tells me how to fix this.

Comment: What version of JBoss AS or JBoss EAP are you targeting?

Comment: Jboss-EAP-6.4 @JamesR.Perkins

Comment: The POM configuration would be helpful and try running with `-e` so that stack trace will show up.